# Emacs Lisp: "if: No catch for tag: --cl-block-nil--, t" when returning nil

Tags: function, emacs, elisp

I tried my hand at writing an elisp function today, all works well except for an error that keeps getting thrown when the function returns nil. Here's the function: (Please excuse the formatting, I'm not really sure how to indent this yet.)

```
(defun byte-is-readable (byte)
  "Determine whether BYTE is readable or not.
Returns t or nil."
  (if (and (<= byte 126) (>= byte 32)) t nil))

;; Read the 100 bytes of a file
;; If 10 in a row are not 'readable', it is safe to assume the file is a binary
(defun is-file-binary (file)
  "Determine whether FILE is a binary file.
Returns t or nil."
  (let* ((i 1)
         (c 0)
         (size (nth 7 (file-attributes file)))
         (lim (if (< size 100) size 100)))
    (while (< i lim)
      (let ((char (with-temp-buffer
                    (insert-file-contents file)
                    (buffer-substring i (+ i 1)))))
        (if (not (byte-is-readable (aref char 0)))
            (setq c (+ c 1))
          (setq c 0))
        (if (= c 10) (return t)))
      (setq i (+ i 1))))
  nil)
```

Calling it like this: `(message "%s" (if (is-file-binary "/path/to/some/file") "true" "false")` works file when returning true, but throws "if: No catch for tag: --cl-block-nil--, t" when returning nil. I'm guessing this is because nil isn't evaluated correctly or something.

How do I fix it?

Comment: You seem to be creating a fresh temp buffer, and loading the contents of FILE into it, on each trip through your WHILE loop. That seems inefficient. Why not wrap the WITH-TEMP-BUFFER around the WHILE? `(with-temp-buffer (insert-file-contents file) (while (< i lim) (let ((char (buffer-substring i (1+ i)))) ... ))` That way, you only have to load FILE's contents once, instead of up to 100 times -- for small files, it won't make a difference, but, since you're loading the entirety of the file into the buffer, for large files it very well might. (Extra credit: Only load the bytes you need.)

Comment: Also, you don't need to break from the WHILE loop at all; you can simply let it exhaust itself, after which you'll have the count of "readable" bytes in C. Then, replace the bare NIL at the end of your LET form with `(< c 10)`, and the function will return T if there are fewer than ten "readable" bytes, or NIL if there are ten or more.

Comment: You could also get rid of the LIM binding, because you're only using it in one place; just remove that binding from the LET binding form, then use `(if (< size 100) size 100)` form to the second argument for the < call in your WHILE test.

Comment: @AaronMiller: Consider rephrasing your comments as an answer. They provide as much of an answer as does the answer by wvxvw, for instance.

Comment: You don't need all this: `(if (and (<= byte 126) (>= byte 32)) t nil))`, unless you really care about `t` as the non-`nil` value. This suffices: `(and (<= byte 126) (>= byte 32))`.

Comment: `(if (< size 100) size 100)` is just `(min size 100)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error comes from the fact that you used `return` in your code. This is a macro that has only meaningfull expansion in the context of some other `cl` macros, such as, for example `loop`.

I would encourage you to use `loop` rather then `while` because it allows to hide uninteresting implementation details such as counters, the `throw` - `catch` mechanism etc. But if you wanted for whatever reason to use `while` the way to break from `while` loop is to use:

```
(catch 'label (while <condition> ... (throw 'label <result>)))
```

---

The version of your code using `loop`.

```
(defun byte-readable-p (byte)
  "Determine whether BYTE is readable or not.
Returns t or nil."
  (cl-case byte
    ((?\n ?\r ?\t) t)
    (otherwise (and (<= byte 126) (>= byte 32)))))

(defun file-binary-p (file)
  "Determine whether FILE is a binary file.
Returns t or nil."
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert-file-contents file)
    (cl-loop for c across
             (buffer-substring-no-properties
              1 (min 100 (buffer-size)))
             thereis (not (byte-readable-p c)))))

(file-binary-p (expand-file-name "~/.emacs"))
nil

(file-binary-p (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/elpa/w3m-20131021.2047/w3m.elc"))
t
```

---

Or, even shorter version, using high-order functions:

```
(defun file-binary-p (file)
  "Determine whether FILE is a binary file.
Returns t or nil."
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert-file-contents file)
    (cl-find-if-not 'byte-readable-p
                    (buffer-substring-no-properties
                     1 (min 100 (buffer-size))))))
```

Note that traditionally in Lisp code functions returning boolean values (often called "predicates") are named using the scheme: `<word>p` or `<word>-<word>-p` rather then `is-<word>`.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks. I'm a bit confused about what the functions do though. Do they check that all 100 bytes are "readable"? Because then that would fail with files that do have "readable" chars (elf files have the letters ELF at the start, and zips start with PK), and yet it doesn't.

Comment: @ronmrdechai the functions search for the first byte (actually character) within the hundred or less bytes at the beginning of the file which is outside the range set by `byte-readable-p`.